# Azure Automation - Runbook to auto-restart a web app once a day

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-automation

I do not have much experience with PowerShell at all - what I'd like to do is use my Azure Automation service to set up a runbook that will automatically restart one of my Azure web apps every night at 1am.

Is it possible to accomplish this with Powershell/Azure Automation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is perfectly possible, you need to create an Azure Automation account, create a runbook tied to a schedule and use something like this:

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection" # this is the default connection created when you provision the Automation account,
                                         # you might need to change this to your own connection name
$servicePrincipalConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

$null = Add-AzureRmAccount `
    -ServicePrincipal `
    -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
    -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
    -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint

$null = Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId 'SUB_GUID' ` # Needed if you have more than 1 subscription

Restart-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName xxx -Name WebAppName
```

Comment: I am getting that restart-azurermwebapp isn't a valid command when i try to add this as a runbook.

Comment: you need to import modules first, if you can't figure it out - create a new question and post a link here